# Выполнение метода в другом потоке

Tags: android, многопоточность

В android есть необходимость выполнять любые взаимодействия с "Интернетом" в другом потоке, но иногда есть нужда всё же подождать результата от сервера и далее что-то с этим делать и конечно же хотелось бы не городить всяких лишних костылей в основном коде для взаимодействия с View компонентами. Немного подумав решил сделать нечто подобное:

```
private void initRequest(){

    final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message message;

            if(Utils.isNetworkConnected(MainActivity.this)){
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(INIT_HOST);

                httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                try {
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                    String strEntity = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strEntity);

                    Global_Variables.COORDS_INTERVAL = jsonObject.getInt(Constance.INIT_RECORD_INTERVAL);
                    Global_Variables.POST_INTERVAL = jsonObject.getInt(Constance.INIT_SEND_INTERVAL);
                    Global_Variables.TIME_CHECK_SPEED = jsonObject.getInt(Constance.INIT_SPEED_INTERVAL);
                    Global_Variables.TRIGGER_SPEED = jsonObject.getInt(Constance.INIT_TRIGGER_SPEED);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    message = new Message();
                    message.obj = "Failed send init request!";
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    message = new Message();
                    message.obj = "Unsuccessful receiving entity!";
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    message = new Message();
                    message.obj = "Failed parse Json!";
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }else{
                message = new Message();
                message.obj = "Check Internet connection!";
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });

    thread.setName("Init request");

    thread.start();

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Thread "+thread.getName()+" interrupted!");
    }

}
```

За пример взял один из функционалов моего приложения. В сам выполняемый функционал вдаваться смысла не вижу, хотелось бы обратить внимание на такие моменты как: **Handler** (необходимый для взаимодействия с UI потоком), и метод **join()** для потока, который необходим, чтобы указать потоку, в котором мы стартовали поток **thread**, что ему необходимо дождаться завершения потока **thread**, это необходимо для того, чтобы глобальные данные до этого никто не успел заюзать. Что всё это даёт? А то, что вы спокойно выполняете метод в другом потоке без лишнего кода в основном коде и при всём этом главный поток ожидает вашего завершения, а в результате ещё и можете провзаимодействовать с UI потоком. Единственным недостатком всего этого вижу то, что результат имеет смысл слать только под конец потока ибо если это сделать в середине, то код в **handler** не выполнится из-за **join()**, пока весь поток не проделает работу до конца. А теперь вопрос: что вы обо всём этом думаете, придумал ли я интересный способ или написал какую-то чушь?

Comment: Чем `AsyncTask` не подошёл?

Comment: Уже есть готовые библиотеки для работы с сетью, например  retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/ он инкапсулирует всю логику по обеспечению асинхронности, парсингу данных и предлагает удобные коллбэки для уведомления ui, есть поддержка выполнения синхронных запросов

Comment: @Suvitruf AsyncTask разве стопит основной поток, чтобы тот подождал завершения основного потока?

Comment: стопить основной поток нельзя. Это очень ужасно.

Comment: @metalurgus Вы скорее всего правы, при длительной операции я могу словить ANR

Comment: Есть же родной java'овский `Callable`/`executor.submit`/`Future.get`. Можно убрать handler, обработку исключений в коде работы с сетью, и ловить эти исключения при вызове `future.get`.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос, интересное решение. Тоже всегда было самому интересно кто и как справляется с этой задачей, в дополнение лишь распишу как реализую это я. 
У меня есть свой класс CallBack:

```
public class CallBack<T> {
    public void onSuccess() {
    }

    public void onSuccess(T result) {
    }

    public void onFail(String message) {

    }

    public void onFailure(T result) {

    }

}
```

Для работы с API методами для GET И POST запросов я использую библиотеку [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). На мой взгляд одна из самых лучших либ, которая постоянно обновляется и развивается. 
К примеру есть метод на получение списка неких объектов:

```
public static void getTestObjectsList(final String url, final Context context, final CallBack<ArrayList<TestObject>> callBack) {

        if (!Server.isOnline(context)) {
            callBack.onFail(context.getString(R.string.no_internet_error));
            return;
        }


        Server.getAsyncHttpClient(context).get(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray jsonArray) {

                ArrayList<TestObject> testObjects = new ArrayList<>();

                if (!(jsonArray.length() > 0)) {
                    callBack.onSuccess(testObjects);
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
                        testObject.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                        testObject.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        testObject.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));

                        testObjects.add(testObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                callBack.onSuccess(testObjects);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                callBack.onFail(errorResponse.getString("error"));
            }
        });

    }
```

Где `Server.getAsyncHttpClient(context)` возвращает `new AsyncHttpClient()`. Вся эта штука выполняется в отдельном потоке и в отдельном классе.
Я люблю использовать такой подход: если есть, к примеру, объект TestObject, то все операции, которые происходят с ним я описываю в классе TestObjectManager.

Как я это использую. К примеру вызываю в своем `Activity` запрос:

```
TestObjectManager.getTestObjectsList(url, getApplicationContext(), new CallBack<ArrayList<TestObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<TestObject> testObjects) {
              //сюда приходит положительный результат. Здесь можно установить адаптер, скрыть прогресс бар и т.д. 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(String error) {
               showShortMessage(error);//здесь просто показываем ошибку в случае неудачи
            }
    });
```

Как мы видим, этот код дожидается результата от выполнения запроса, и в любом случае его получит, будь он положительный или отрицательный. Вообще надеюсь поделился опытом по делу) И! жду конструктивной критики)

Comment: Ваше решение тоже довольно интересное

Comment: для всего этого уже есть готовое решение в retrofit или можно просто использовать OkHttp

Comment: @nick_kryloff а в чем принципиальное отличие okhttp от asynchttp?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя блокировать main thred больше чем на 5 сек, андройд расценит это как anr и грохнит таску