# Как вернуть значение из thread Java

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который отправляет данные на сервер. Внутри метода создается новый поток, в котором и происходит отправка на сервер. Как теперь правильно вернуть значение переменной `STATUS_SEND` из потока?

```
public boolean sendTrackerInfo() {
    STATUS_SEND = false;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
                String result="";
                URL url_string = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url_string.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.connect();
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                byte[] data = jsonArrayToSend.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                Log.d(TAG, "data: " + jsonArrayToSend.toString());
                dataOutputStream.write(data);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
                result = connection.getResponseMessage();
                jsonFromServer = convertInputStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "resultRequest: " + result);
                Log.d(TAG, "jsonFromServer: " + jsonFromServer.toString());

                if (result.equals("OK")) {
                    STATUS_SEND = true;
                }
                else {
                    STATUS_SEND = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    return STATUS_SEND;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких задач я практически всегда использую свой класс CallBack.

```
public class CallBack<T> {

    public void onSuccess() {
    }

    public void onSuccess(T result) {
    }

    public void onFail(String message) {

    }

    public void onFailure(T result) {

    }

}
```

Перепишем Ваш метод, с использованием данного класса:

```
public void sendTrackerInfo(final CallBack callBack) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
                String result="";
                URL url_string = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url_string.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.connect();
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                byte[] data = jsonArrayToSend.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                Log.d(TAG, "data: " + jsonArrayToSend.toString());
                dataOutputStream.write(data);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
                result = connection.getResponseMessage();
                jsonFromServer = convertInputStreamToString(connection.getInputStream());
                Log.d(TAG, "resultRequest: " + result);
                Log.d(TAG, "jsonFromServer: " + jsonFromServer.toString());

                if (result.equals("OK")) {
                    callBack.onSuccess();
                }
                else {
                     callBack.onFail("error");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 callBack.onFail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Вызываться Ваш метод будет таким способом:

```
sendTrackerInfo(new CallBack() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                          method(true);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFail(String error) {
                           method(false);
                        }
                    });
```

Поскольку CallBack у меня template class, то в него можно загонять любые типы объектов и принимать в `onSuccess(YourObject yourObject)` тоже

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что чтобы вернуть значение `STATUS_SEND = true`, необходимо его добавить в `Callback` класс в метод `onSuccess()` ?

Comment: Смысла нет, ведь если у вас в result придет ОК, то коллбэк вернется в onSuccess. А зачем же еще булин проверять, если и так понятно что все хорошо?=) Другое дело, если от сервера вам необходимо получить определенные значения, или скажем, список объектов. Тогда смысл есть

Comment: Переменная используется в качестве флага и передается в другой метод.

Comment: обновил вызов функции..

Comment: Колбэки будут вызваны в том же потоке. Попробуйте, например, сделать в onSuccess какой-нить UI вызов, получите исключение. Их необходимо вызывать либо через Activity.runOnUIThread либо через Hander.post. Хэндлер либо создавать и передавать в sendTrackerInfo вместе с колбэком, либо внутри потока Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).

Comment: `method(true);` - can not resolve method

Comment: =) ну это же я пример привел просто

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, а что думаете по поводу `AsyncTask` для этой задачи?

Comment: @Dev_Vlad думаю, что мастхэв. Щас линкану тему, которую обсуждали ранее

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485022/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5/485033#485033

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я имею в виду сравнение `AsyncTask` и `Callback`. Что лучше/хуже и т.д. ?

Comment: Это совсем разные вещи. Сравнивать их нельзя, разве что комбинировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35965/discussion-between-dev-vlad-and--).

Answer (score 4):

Используйте интерфейс [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Boolean> result = es.submit(new Callable() {

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        // Ваш исполняемый код в другом потоке...
    }

});   
return result.get();
```

Вот только вам нужно продумать логику, как корректно реализовать многопоточное выполнение метода. В представленном коде метод `sendTrackerInfo()` по сути является блокирующим, поскольку метод `get()` дожидается завершения выполнения потока и только после этого возвращает результат. Поэтому, скорее всего, понадобится реализовать [callback-функционал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826212/java-executors-how-to-be-notified-without-blocking-when-a-task-completes).

Comment: Если я добавлю ваш код внутри метода `sendTrackerInfo()`, это будет правильно? (Правильность в плане написания кода)

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Отвечая на ваш комментарий, то добавление моего кода не решит проблему, которую я описал в последнем абзаце.